# Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1

Tags: java, android

андроид студио в интеллии, выскакивает такая ошибка:

Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
разница которая даёт такую ошибку это добавление
к примеру параметрра:

android:layout_marginTop="20" или вообще изменение числа в марджинТопе на другое, то есть параметр уже был такой. при том не на каждое изменение этого параметра ругается в других виджетах или текстах.

С JSON не знаком.

Comment: даже на параметр марджин можно не небращать внимания. Просто лишнюю пустую строку добавил, ошибка появляется. убрал. ошибка исчезла

Comment: проблема самоулетучивается, когда по второй раз запускаешь код, данная надпись в буилде пропадает, и прога норма запускается. и так каждый раз изменяя что либо, первый раз не запускается, второй раз норма. может что либо c другими компонентами. не знаю.

Comment: А зачем Вы вообще файлы разметки читаете, да ещё и `JsonReader'ом`?

Comment: в интеллии есть снизу кнопка с видвигающимся окном, которая называется build, так вот, окно автоматически выдвигается когда запускаешь программу, там показан ход буилдинга проги, и в проблемах высветилось красным то что я написал. то есть не пользовался ничем. кстати создал новый проект, проблема перестала появляться, видимо сборка слетела мавеновская со всякими градлами и прочим чего Я ещё не знаю. БСОД был когда была интеллия запущена. Сразу не придал значение этому.

Comment: Сделайте чистку кешей (`invalidate caches` в меню `file`, `clean` или `rebuild project` в меню `build`) - что-то из этого должно помочь